# Access Azure VM filesystem via machine IP

Tags: networking, azure

Is it possible to access Azure VM filesystem via machine IP? So given two virtual machines

- SERVER1
- CLIENT1

Can I get to CLIENT1 file system from the SERVER1 by

\\{CLIENT IP}\c$\temp

I can't seem to do it. I can ping the VMs from each other but I can't see the machines on the network. I know that you can use an [Azure file share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) to do this but I'm trying to prove something works through Citrix (to be deployed on physical boxes) but I have to do this on Azure as there are no test servers available.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the below ports have been opened, and allowed from only each other:

- Microsoft file sharing SMB: 135-139 TCP and UDP
- Direct-hosted SMB traffic without NetBIOS: 445 TCP and UDP

If you are able to, ensure that you create these connections over private networking where possible. If it must traverse a public network, create an IPsec tunnel. **NEVER OPEN THESE PORTS** to the public internet.